# Generating a general term for a taylor polynomial

Tags: taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be the function given by $$ f\left(x\right) = \sin\left(5x +\frac{ \pi }{4}\right)$$ Let $P\left(x\right)$ represent Taylor polynomial of $f$ centred at $x =0$. Generate the general term for $P\left(x\right)$

My Solution: $$f'\left(x\right)=5\cos\left(5x +\frac{ \pi }{4}\right) = \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$f''\left(x\right) =-25\sin\left(5x +\frac{ \pi }{4}\right) = -\frac{25}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$f'''\left(x\right)-125\cos\left(5x +\frac{ \pi }{4}\right) = -\frac{125}{\sqrt{2}}$$
From here I can see that the signs alternate every two terms. I know that for a series in which the sign alternates every term I simply use $\left(-1\right)^n$ as sign representation. However, in this case I am at a loss. Would this series even be considered alternating? 
For my general term I have $$\frac{5^nx^n}{\sqrt{2}n!}$$ but I do not know how to deal with the sign. Any advice? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and most understandable way to deal with the sign is just to use cases:
$$
f^{[n]} (0) \frac{x^n}{n!}
=
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{n/2} \dfrac{5^nx^n}{\sqrt{2}n!} & \text{if } n \text{ even} \\
(-1)^{(n-1)/2} \dfrac{5^nx^n}{\sqrt{2}n!} & \text{if } n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
You can also use the floor function:
$$
(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \dfrac{5^nx^n}{\sqrt{2}n!}
$$

Comment: Ah thank you! I never considered using the piecewise function

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It is easier use the identity

$$ \sin t = \frac{1}{2i}( e^{it} - e^{-it} ).$$